# Prevent subview from being added multiple times to UIView subclass when it moves to superview

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios

I want to reuuse my loading overlay. Therefore I have a field in my view controller class, which gets instantiated one time with it.

*Loading overlay:*

```
public class LoadingOverlay : UIView {
    private UIActivityIndicatorView activitySpinner;
    private bool isShown = false;

    public LoadingOverlay () : base ()
    {
    }

    public override void WillMoveToSuperview (UIView newsuper)
    {
        base.WillMoveToSuperview (newsuper);

        if (newsuper != null) {
            isShown = true;

            activitySpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
            AddSubview (activitySpinner);
            activitySpinner.StartAnimating ();

            activitySpinner.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            this.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (activitySpinner, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0));
            this.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (activitySpinner, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0));
        }
    }

    public void Hide ()
    {
        if (isShown) {
            RemoveFromSuperview ();
        }
    }
```

I'm adding it to the view hierarchy in this way:

```
viewShowingLoadingOverlay.InsertSubviewBelow(loadingOverlay, AppDelegate.navigationController.NavigationBar);
```

When I want to get it removed I call the *hide()* method:

```
loading.Hide ();
```

Using this approach the spinner gets added multiple times (for each `InsertSubView`). Creating a new instance of *LoadingOverlay* for each call doesn't show this problem. Now it is clear that `AddSubView` is adding the spinner each time *LoadingOverlay* moves to the parent. My code is in C# but you can provide an Objective-C solution as well.

How can I write my *LoadingOverlay*  class so that the spinner is added only one time?

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. Create the spinner in the constructor of your view. Then add the whole thing to your parent view and remove it again if you don't need it any longer.

Comment: @Krumelur: I already tried that, but I had a few problems. Adding constraints in `WillMoveToSuperview` brings some side effects (errors in the output log). Adding them in the constructor works. Furthermore, I also set the alpha value in the constructor. Now the overlay is only shown the first time! Therefore I set the alpha value in `WillMoveToSuperview` and it seems to work. I didn't changed the way I add or remove the objects from the superview.